# Can Slim interpret a block as Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

Is it possible to define a custom helper method that outputs a `<script>` tag and interprets the `capture`d block as Javascript?

Say I want to wrap my Javascript in an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression). I'd like to be able to write this in my Slim template:

```
= javascript_iife do
  console.log("Hello, world!");
```

And have it compile to this HTML:

```
<script>
  (function() {
    console.log("Hello, world!");
  })();
</script>
```

This helper *almost* does what I want:

```
def javascript_iife(&block)
  javascript = capture(&block)
  raw("<script>(function() {") + javascript + raw("})();</script>")
end
```

But it doesn't interpret the block as Javascript, instead interpreting it as Slim-style HTML (which causes a syntax error). I have to rewrite my Slim template as:

```
= javascript_iife do
  | console.log("Hello, world!");
```

Can I implement the helper in such a way that the original template works as expected? Or could I implement a custom filter (`javascript_iife:`) analogous to the Javascript filter (`javascript:`)?

Comment: not a real answer, but if you use the `coffee:` helper and coffeescript it automatically gets wrapped in an IIFE :D

Comment: @maxpleaner yeah. And if you need to pass some variables from views to coffee block (this is not possible), just make a javascript block before the coffee block which sets the js variables.